# Trying to install libmcrypt-dev in a php5.6 dockerFile

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

I need to run this docker file, but i cant, after some research i found that the libmcrypt is no longer in PHP 5.6, and i should get it from external resources, but i'm just lost. What can i do? (changing PHP version is not a choice)

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install mcrypt

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zip unzip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git-core
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zip unzip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev
RUN apt-get install -y vim cron supervisor
RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring pdo_mysql tokenizer
RUN apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libmcrypt-dev libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
RUN set -ex; \
    \
    savedAptMark="$(apt-mark showmanual)"; \
    \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    ; \
    \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr; \
    docker-php-ext-install gd mysqli opcache; \
    \
# reset apt-mark's "manual" list so that "purge --auto-remove" will remove all build dependencies
    apt-mark auto '.*' > /dev/null; \
    apt-mark manual $savedAptMark; \
    ldd "$(php -r 'echo ini_get("extension_dir");')"/*.so \
        | awk '/=>/ { print $3 }' \
        | sort -u \
        | xargs -r dpkg-query -S \
        | cut -d: -f1 \
        | sort -u \
        | xargs -rt apt-mark manual; \
    \
    apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# set recommended PHP.ini settings
# see https://secure.php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php
RUN { \
        echo 'opcache.memory_consumption=128'; \
        echo 'opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8'; \
        echo 'opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000'; \
        echo 'opcache.revalidate_freq=2'; \
        echo 'opcache.fast_shutdown=1'; \
        echo 'opcache.enable_cli=1'; \
    } > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache-recommended.ini


CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

[terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pai5s.png)

I tried to change some versions of the dockerfile and getting the lib from external resources

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/phpseclib/mcrypt_compat and also stop using mcrypt asap.